# How do I recognize a line break with a switch case that evaluates a char in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a switch case that evaluates each character from some input. The switch case evaluates spaces and tabs fine but when it goes to evaluate a line break I can't seem to find a case that it works with.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char curr = input.charAt(i);
        switch (curr) {
             case 'a':
                     //does stuff
                     break;
    .
    .
    .       
             //space case
             case ' ': 
                    outputCode = outputCode + curr + " read \n";
                    break;

             //tab case
             case ' ':
                    outputCode = outputCode + curr + " read \n";
                    break;

             //new line case, the issue
             case '\n':
                    break;  
             default:
                    outputCode = outputCode + "Error Found at line " +     LineNumber +  curr + " is an Invalid Character.";
                    break;
```

Comment: Use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) rather than a hard-coded `\n` in order to be compatible across platforms.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question--are you saying that you can't create an `input` string that has `\n` characters?  Where does `input` come from?  In fact, I believe we need more specific information about what, exactly, the problem is.  (Most of the answerers seem to think they know what the problem is, but I'm betting they're all wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

new line character will be platform dependent. You should probably use -

```
java.lang.System.lineSeparator()
```

for Java7+ OR

```
System.getProperty("line.seperator")
```

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator. 
>   On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

As you can see in case of windows it wont be a single char. Change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not recognize `\n` you can try `\r\n`.

`\r` for carriage return

---

Different Operating System may use different standard.

- If you are using Windows, try: `\r\n`
- If you are using MAC OS X, try: `\n`
- If you are using MAC OS 9 orprevious versions, try: `\r`
- If you are using Unix: `\n`

---

However, do note that `\r\n` are actually ***2 characters***. So if you want to perform a switch with it, you may want to switch on a `String` instead:

```
String ls= System.getProperty("line.separator");
switch (ls){
    case "\n":      System.out.println("Using Unix / Mac OSX");
                    break;
    case "\r\n":    System.out.println("Using Windows");
                    break;
    case "\r":      System.out.println("Using Mac OS 9 or previous");
                    break;                      
}
```

**My output:**

```
Using Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the new line is `\r\n`.

You would need to add another case for `\r` to do nothing in order to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can *borrow* the approach form `java.util.Scanner` class. Look at their [LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.0LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN):

```
LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN = "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]";
```