# line break with case switch javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, switch-statement, line-breaks

I'm new; thank you so much for helping me :)

I have a long paragraph I want to output, given a certain value.

I tried to make a line break in a case switch with \n and < br > and tried the methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569821/how-do-i-recognize-a-line-break-with-a-switch-case-that-evaluates-a-char-in-java) -- all of which I put inside the quotations where I wanted my breaks to occur. None of them seem to work. However, there might be a way to create a line break with overflow and CSS? I'm not sure, let me know.

Here's my code so far. **Basically, it appears on one long line that goes outside my browser** and I don't know why:

```js
var determineInfo = function(value) {
  var info = "";
  //console.log(value);
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      info = "Radio waves have long and largely varying wavelengths, from 1mm to more than 100km. They are emitted by planets, stars, pulsars, and other celestial ongoings. Man-made sources of radio waves include television signals, cell phones, and wifi. These waves are used for communication via shortwave radio and FM stereo. A small dose of radio waves exposure is not too harmful, but  with large and unprotected doses, radio waves can cause cancer. Exposure to radio waves can also cause retinal degeneration, increase the metabolic rate, increase the blood flow, cause cell death and DNA damage, which can lead to necrosis (organ failure).";
      break;
    case 2:
      info = "Microwaves are high frequency waves with a wavelength between 0.1 and 5 cm. Microwaves are used in cell phone transmitters and, shockingly, in microwave ovens. Microwaves are used to cook food because they cause certain molecules to vibrate strongly, resulting in heat. However, this can cause burns on bare human skin. Long exposure to microwaves has also been shown to cause cataracts.";
      break;
    case 3:
      info = "Infrared waves are produced by any source of heat or energy. Infrared waves are often used in sensors. Since all living things emit heat, these sensors can be used to detect the presence of people. Infrared waves have wavelengths between 10 microns and 30 cm. Most infrared radiation that we are exposed to on a daily basis is too weak to do any significant harm. However, long-term exposure to high intensity radiation can cause wrinkles and premature aging. ";
      break;
    case 4:
      info = "Visible light paragraph not written yet";
      break;
    case 5:
      info = "Ultraviolet radiation paragraph not written yet";
      break;
    case 6:
      info = "X-ray paragraph not written yet";
      break;
    case 7:
      info = "Gamma ray paragraph not written yet";
      break;
  }
  //console.log(word);
  return info;
};
```

Full code:

```js
// VAL SCORE -> WORD

var determineWord = function(value) {
  var word = "";
  //console.log(value);
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      word = "Radio waves";
      break;
    case 2:
      word = "Microwaves";
      break;
    case 3:
      word = "Infrared radiation";
      break;
    case 4:
      word = "Visible light";
      break;
    case 5:
      word = "Ultraviolet radiation";
      break;
    case 6:
      word = "X-ray";
      break;
    case 7:
      word = "Gamma ray";
      break;
  }
  //console.log(word);
  return word;
};


var determineInfo = function(value) {
  var info = "";
  //console.log(value);
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      info = "Radio waves have long and largely varying wavelengths, from 1mm to more than 100km. They are emitted by planets, stars, pulsars, and other celestial ongoings. Man-made sources of radio waves include television signals, cell phones, and wifi. These waves are used for communication via shortwave radio and FM stereo. A small dose of radio waves exposure is not too harmful, but  with large and unprotected doses, radio waves can cause cancer. Exposure to radio waves can also cause retinal degeneration, increase the metabolic rate, increase the blood flow, cause cell death and DNA damage, which can lead to necrosis (organ failure).";
      break;
    case 2:
      info = "Microwaves are high frequency waves with a wavelength between 0.1 and 5 cm. Microwaves are used in cell phone transmitters and, shockingly, in microwave ovens. Microwaves are used to cook food because they cause certain molecules to vibrate strongly, resulting in heat. However, this can cause burns on bare human skin. Long exposure to microwaves has also been shown to cause cataracts.";
      break;
    case 3:
      info = "Infrared waves are produced by any source of heat or energy. Infrared waves are often used in sensors. Since all living things emit heat, these sensors can be used to detect the presence of people. Infrared waves have wavelengths between 10 microns and 30 cm. Most infrared radiation that we are exposed to on a daily basis is too weak to do any significant harm. However, long-term exposure to high intensity radiation can cause wrinkles and premature aging. ";
      break;
    case 4:
      info = "Visible light";
      break;
    case 5:
      info = "Ultraviolet radiation";
      break;
    case 6:
      info = "X-ray";
      break;
    case 7:
      info = "Gamma ray";
      break;
  }
  //console.log(word);
  return info;
};

// SLIDER

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(determineWord(ui.value));
      $("#waves").val(determineInfo(ui.value));
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val(determineWord($("#slider").slider("value")));
  $("#waves").val(determineInfo($("#slider").slider("value")));
});


// dropdown

function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
  this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
  this.val = '';
  this.index = -1;
  this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function() {
    var obj = this;

    obj.dd.on('click', function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });

    obj.opts.on('click', function() {
      var opt = $(this);
      obj.val = opt.text();
      obj.index = opt.index();
      obj.placeholder.text('+ PROTECTION: ' + obj.val);
    });
  },
  getValue: function() {
    return this.val;
  },
  getIndex: function() {
    return this.index;
  }
}

$(function() {

  var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

  $(document).click(function() {
    // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
  });

});


// scores

$(document).ready(function() {

  var scoreConstants = {
    'Air': 1,
    'Hat': 2,
    'Sunscreen':3,
    'Sweater':4,
    'Glass':5,
    'Brick': 6,
    'Steel': 7,
    'Lead': 8,
    
    'Radio waves': 10,
    'Microwaves': 20,
    'Infrared radiation': 30,
    'Visible light': 40,
    'Ultraviolet radiation': 50,
    'X-ray':60,
    'Gamma ray':70
  };

  var evalScore = function(selectedValues) {
    var totalScore = 0;
    $.each(selectedValues, function(k, v) {
      totalScore += scoreConstants[v];
    });
    return totalScore;
  }
  
  var getScoreInfo = function(score) {
    var scoreInfo = 'Info: ';
    if (score >= 10) {
      scoreInfo += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
    } else if (score >= 20) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
    } else if (score >= 30) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
   } else if (score >= 40) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by A';
   } else if (score >= 50) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by B';
   } else if (score >= 60) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by C';
    } else if (score >= 70) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by D';
   }
    return scoreInfo;
  }

  var getScoreLabel = function(score) {
    var scoreValue = 'Score: ';
    if (score == 11) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 12) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 13) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 14) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 15) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 16) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 17) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 18) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 21) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 22) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 23) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 24) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 25) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 26) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 27) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 28) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 31) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 32) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 33) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 34) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 35) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 36) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 37) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 38) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 41) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 42) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 43) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 44) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 45) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 46) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 47) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 48) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 51) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 52) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 53) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 54) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 55) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 56) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 57) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 58) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 61) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 62) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 63) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 64) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 65) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 66) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 67) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 68) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 71) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 72) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 73) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 74) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 75) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 76) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 77) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 78) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
   }
    return scoreValue;
  }

  $('body').on('click', '#evaluate', function(e) {
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
var dropdown = $.trim($('.wrapper-dropdown-1').children('span').text().split(':')[1]);
var selectedValues = [amount,dropdown];

    var score = evalScore(selectedValues);
    var scoreLabel = getScoreLabel(score);

    var valueString = 'Selected: ';
    if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
      $.each(selectedValues, function(k, v) {
        if (k === (selectedValues.length - 1)) {
          valueString += v;
        } else {
          valueString += v + ', '
        }
      });
    } else {
      valueString += 'None';
    }

    var $result = $('#result');
    $result.html(scoreLabel);

    var $displayValues = $('#values');
    $displayValues.html(valueString);

  var $info = $('#info');
    $info.html(scoreInfo);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background:transparent;
}

::selection {
  background: #ffffcc;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffffcc;
}

/* protection */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 40px 0 0 -260px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 {
  position: relative;
  /* Enable absolute positionning for children and pseudo elements */
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Styles */
  background: #ffcccc;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Styles */
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown li:hover a {
  background: #ffe6e6;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1.active:after {
  border-color: #9bc7de transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.no-opacity .wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
  pointer-events: auto;
  /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity .wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/** slider **/

.text {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

option {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

option:hover,
option:focus,
option:active {
  background: #ffe6e6;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 305px;
}

#wavescontainer {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 425px;
  width: 105px;
  position:relative;
}

#waves {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  position:relative;
}


#amount {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#slider {
  width: 320px;
  height: 2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 20px;
}

#slider .wavelengths {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

dub {
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.ui-slider {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
  top: -.3em;
  margin-left: -.6em;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
  left: 0;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
  right: 0;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-button,
html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover,
html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.ui-state-default a,
.ui-state-default a:link,
.ui-state-default a:visited,
a.ui-button,
a:link.ui-button,
a:visited.ui-button,
.ui-button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus,
.ui-button:hover,
.ui-button:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
a.ui-button:active,
.ui-button:active,
.ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-dialog-title {
  font-size: 110% !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #000000 !important;
}

/* results */

button {
  background: #ccffcc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px double white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

button:active {
  background: #e6ffe6;
}

h4 {
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:60px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal;
}

h5 {
  margin-left:100px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://jsfiddle.net/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  For [10 sec] exposure and [100 watts] of given wavelength. All fields are required.
  <hr>
</div>
<!-- colors: #ffffcc, #ccffcc, #ffcc99, #ffcccc -->
<p>
  <label for="amount">WAVELENGTH:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#000; font-weight:normal; width:150px; background:#ccffcc; letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center;">
</p>

<p>
  <label for="waves">INFO:</label>
  <input type="text" id="waves" readonly style="border:0; background:#ffffcc; width:200px; height:100px;">
  </p>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="wavelengths">
    10<sup>3</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-2</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-5</sup>
    <dub></dub> .5x10<sup>-6</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-8</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-10</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-12</sup>
  </div>
</div>


<section class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
      <span>+ PROTECTION (2 feet)</span>
      <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
        <li><a href="#" value="Air">Air</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Hat">Hat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Sunscreen">Sunscreen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Sweater">Sweater</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Glass">Glass</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Brick">Brick</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Steel">Steel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Lead">Lead</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<br>
<button id="evaluate" type="button">READY</button>
<h4 id="result"></h4>
<h5 id="values"></h5>
<h5 id="info"></h5>


<img src="https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png" name="fate" style="height:400px;">



<!-- WOUNDED fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png"; 
  DEAD fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/cYe8Ak/149496258477050_3.png";
-->
```

Comment: How are you using the result of the function? If you're assigning it to `.innerHTML`, `<br>` should work.

Comment: Why are you using `switch/case`? Just use an array.

Comment: Browsers normally do line wrapping, why do you think you need to add line breaks yourself?

Comment: What does the switch statement have to do with adding line breaks?

Comment: Do you mean a line break in code layout so it's not a huge line in your source, or a line break in HTML layout once you insert it into the document, or a line break in text layout if you're giving it to `console.log` or `alert`?

Comment: @Barmar when the output appears it is one line and doesn't fit into my container. I'm using switch/case because I'm switching the numbers on a slider to output text

Comment: @Amadan I mean a line break in my html layout once it's inserted into the document

Comment: Are you using `<pre>` in the HTML to prevent it from wrapping?

Comment: @user3689565 Why do you need a switch? Just put them in an array, and use `return array[value]`.

Comment: @Barmar i was using a switch for another part of the code and assumed it would work just as well as an if/else statement. I've never had text appear in one line if it could overflow to the next line, so I'm confused. Granted, I primarily work in CSS and HTML and barely know enough about javascript to even know _what_ to research. Thanks so much for taking the time to respond to me, I know it can be a pain trying to explain things to a newbie

Comment: There's nothing special about Javascript. When it puts the text into the DOM, it's rendered the same as if you'd written ordinary HTML yourself. You need to post your HTML and Javascript that's displaying the paragraphs.

Comment: @Barmar [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ch889v18/30/) my jsfiddle. i'm talking about the yellow part

Comment: It's because you're putting it into an `<input>` box. These don't have multiple lines. Why don't you display it in a DIV? If you need it to be a form field, use `<textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the field you're putting the text into is an `<input>`, and these can only display one line.

Change it to `<textarea>` and it will automatically wrap.

```js
// VAL SCORE -> WORD

var determineWord = function(value) {
  var word = "";
  //console.log(value);
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      word = "Radio waves";
      break;
    case 2:
      word = "Microwaves";
      break;
    case 3:
      word = "Infrared radiation";
      break;
    case 4:
      word = "Visible light";
      break;
    case 5:
      word = "Ultraviolet radiation";
      break;
    case 6:
      word = "X-ray";
      break;
    case 7:
      word = "Gamma ray";
      break;
  }
  //console.log(word);
  return word;
};


var determineInfo = function(value) {
  var info = "";
  //console.log(value);
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      info = "Radio waves have long and largely varying wavelengths, from 1mm to more than 100km. They are emitted by planets, stars, pulsars, and other celestial ongoings. Man-made sources of radio waves include television signals, cell phones, and wifi. These waves are used for communication via shortwave radio and FM stereo. A small dose of radio waves exposure is not too harmful, but  with large and unprotected doses, radio waves can cause cancer. Exposure to radio waves can also cause retinal degeneration, increase the metabolic rate, increase the blood flow, cause cell death and DNA damage, which can lead to necrosis (organ failure).";
      break;
    case 2:
      info = "Microwaves are high frequency waves with a wavelength between 0.1 and 5 cm. Microwaves are used in cell phone transmitters and, shockingly, in microwave ovens. Microwaves are used to cook food because they cause certain molecules to vibrate strongly, resulting in heat. However, this can cause burns on bare human skin. Long exposure to microwaves has also been shown to cause cataracts.";
      break;
    case 3:
      info = "Infrared waves are produced by any source of heat or energy. Infrared waves are often used in sensors. Since all living things emit heat, these sensors can be used to detect the presence of people. Infrared waves have wavelengths between 10 microns and 30 cm. Most infrared radiation that we are exposed to on a daily basis is too weak to do any significant harm. However, long-term exposure to high intensity radiation can cause wrinkles and premature aging. ";
      break;
    case 4:
      info = "Visible light";
      break;
    case 5:
      info = "Ultraviolet radiation";
      break;
    case 6:
      info = "X-ray";
      break;
    case 7:
      info = "Gamma ray";
      break;
  }
  //console.log(word);
  return info;
};

// SLIDER

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 7,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(determineWord(ui.value));
      $("#waves").val(determineInfo(ui.value));
    }
  });
  $("#amount").val(determineWord($("#slider").slider("value")));
  $("#waves").val(determineInfo($("#slider").slider("value")));
});


// dropdown

function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
  this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
  this.val = '';
  this.index = -1;
  this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents: function() {
    var obj = this;

    obj.dd.on('click', function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });

    obj.opts.on('click', function() {
      var opt = $(this);
      obj.val = opt.text();
      obj.index = opt.index();
      obj.placeholder.text('+ PROTECTION: ' + obj.val);
    });
  },
  getValue: function() {
    return this.val;
  },
  getIndex: function() {
    return this.index;
  }
}

$(function() {

  var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

  $(document).click(function() {
    // all dropdowns
    $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
  });

});


// scores

$(document).ready(function() {

  var scoreConstants = {
    'Air': 1,
    'Hat': 2,
    'Sunscreen':3,
    'Sweater':4,
    'Glass':5,
    'Brick': 6,
    'Steel': 7,
    'Lead': 8,
    
    'Radio waves': 10,
    'Microwaves': 20,
    'Infrared radiation': 30,
    'Visible light': 40,
    'Ultraviolet radiation': 50,
    'X-ray':60,
    'Gamma ray':70
  };

  var evalScore = function(selectedValues) {
    var totalScore = 0;
    $.each(selectedValues, function(k, v) {
      totalScore += scoreConstants[v];
    });
    return totalScore;
  }
  
  var getScoreInfo = function(score) {
    var scoreInfo = 'Info: ';
    if (score >= 10) {
      scoreInfo += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
    } else if (score >= 20) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
    } else if (score >= 30) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
   } else if (score >= 40) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by A';
   } else if (score >= 50) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by B';
   } else if (score >= 60) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by C';
    } else if (score >= 70) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by D';
   }
    return scoreInfo;
  }

  var getScoreLabel = function(score) {
    var scoreValue = 'Score: ';
    if (score == 11) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 12) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 13) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 14) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 15) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 16) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 17) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 18) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 21) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 22) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 23) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 24) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 25) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 26) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 27) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a microwave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 28) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 31) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 32) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 33) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 34) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 35) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 36) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 37) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by infrared radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 38) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 41) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 42) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 43) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 44) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 45) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 46) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 47) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by visible light';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 48) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 51) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 52) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 53) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 54) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 55) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 56) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 57) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by ultraviolet radiation';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 58) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 61) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 62) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 63) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 64) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 65) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 66) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 67) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by an X-ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 68) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
      
    } else if (score == 71) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 72) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 73) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
   } else if (score == 74) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png";
    } else if (score == 75) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 76) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";  
    } else if (score == 77) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a gamma ray';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
    } else if (score == 78) {
      scoreValue += 'You have been hit by a radio wave';
      fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png";
   }
    return scoreValue;
  }

  $('body').on('click', '#evaluate', function(e) {
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
var dropdown = $.trim($('.wrapper-dropdown-1').children('span').text().split(':')[1]);
var selectedValues = [amount,dropdown];

    var score = evalScore(selectedValues);
    var scoreLabel = getScoreLabel(score);

    var valueString = 'Selected: ';
    if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
      $.each(selectedValues, function(k, v) {
        if (k === (selectedValues.length - 1)) {
          valueString += v;
        } else {
          valueString += v + ', '
        }
      });
    } else {
      valueString += 'None';
    }

    var $result = $('#result');
    $result.html(scoreLabel);

    var $displayValues = $('#values');
    $displayValues.html(valueString);

  var $info = $('#info');
    $info.html(scoreInfo);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background:transparent;
}

::selection {
  background: #ffffcc;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffffcc;
}

/* protection */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 40px 0 0 -260px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.wrapper:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 {
  position: relative;
  /* Enable absolute positionning for children and pseudo elements */
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Styles */
  background: #ffcccc;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Styles */
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown li:hover a {
  background: #ffe6e6;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-1.active:after {
  border-color: #9bc7de transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.no-opacity .wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-1 .dropdown {
  display: none;
  opacity: 1;
  /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
  pointer-events: auto;
  /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity .wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-1.active .dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/** slider **/

.text {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

option {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

option:hover,
option:focus,
option:active {
  background: #ffe6e6;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 305px;
}

#wavescontainer {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-left: 425px;
  width: 105px;
  position:relative;
}

#waves {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  position:relative;
}


#amount {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#slider {
  width: 320px;
  height: 2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 20px;
}

#slider .wavelengths {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

dub {
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.ui-slider {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 25px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
  top: -.3em;
  margin-left: -.6em;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
  left: 0;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max {
  right: 0;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-button,
html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover,
html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.ui-state-default a,
.ui-state-default a:link,
.ui-state-default a:visited,
a.ui-button,
a:link.ui-button,
a:visited.ui-button,
.ui-button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus,
.ui-button:hover,
.ui-button:focus {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active,
a.ui-button:active,
.ui-button:active,
.ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-state-active a,
.ui-state-active a:link,
.ui-state-active a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-dialog-title {
  font-size: 110% !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #000000 !important;
}

/* results */

button {
  background: #ccffcc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px double white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

button:active {
  background: #e6ffe6;
}

h4 {
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-top:60px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal;
}

h5 {
  margin-left:100px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://jsfiddle.net/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  For [10 sec] exposure and [100 watts] of given wavelength. All fields are required.
  <hr>
</div>
<!-- colors: #ffffcc, #ccffcc, #ffcc99, #ffcccc -->
<p>
  <label for="amount">WAVELENGTH:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#000; font-weight:normal; width:150px; background:#ccffcc; letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center;">
</p>

<p>
  <label for="waves">INFO:</label>
  <textarea id="waves" readonly style="border:0; background:#ffffcc; width:200px; height:100px;"></textarea>
  </p>

<div id="slider">
  <div class="wavelengths">
    10<sup>3</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-2</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-5</sup>
    <dub></dub> .5x10<sup>-6</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-8</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-10</sup>
    <dub></dub> 10<sup>-12</sup>
  </div>
</div>


<section class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
      <span>+ PROTECTION (2 feet)</span>
      <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
        <li><a href="#" value="Air">Air</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Hat">Hat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Sunscreen">Sunscreen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Sweater">Sweater</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Glass">Glass</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Brick">Brick</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Steel">Steel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" value="Lead">Lead</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<br>
<button id="evaluate" type="button">READY</button>
<h4 id="result"></h4>
<h5 id="values"></h5>
<h5 id="info"></h5>


<img src="https://image.ibb.co/eMkFqk/149496258477050.png" name="fate" style="height:400px;">



<!-- WOUNDED fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/kNLgVk/149496258477050_1.png"; 
  DEAD fate.src = "https://image.ibb.co/cYe8Ak/149496258477050_3.png";
-->
```